# Send command from Python to cmd (Windows) and save output

Tags: python, cmd, subprocess, interpreter

I want to create a function that executes several commands on the cmd in Windows. The output of this should be stored in a variable and be returned.

```
def cmd_executer(line):
 #run the "line" command in cmd
 #save the output of the "line" command to a string variable
```

Comment: There is used by `%SystemRoot\System32\cmd.exe` (32-bit version on 32-bit Windows, 64-bit version on 64-bit Windows) respectively `%SystemRoot%\SysWOW64\cmd.exe` (32-bit version on 64-bit Windows) the Windows kernel library function [CreateProcess](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/processthreadsapi/nf-processthreadsapi-createprocessw) with the [STARTUPINFO](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/processthreadsapi/ns-processthreadsapi-startupinfow) structure.

Comment: The [subprocess module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html) is on Windows a Python wrapper module for the function `CreateProcess` and the `STARTUPINFO` structure. So every executable can be run directly using the subprocess module without using `cmd.exe` as it makes no difference for the Windows kernel library function `CreateProcess` which process calls it: `python.exe` or `cmd.exe` (or `explorer.exe` or `cscript.exe` or `wscript.exe` or `powershell.exe` or `java.exe`).

Answer (score 0):

```
import os    
def interpreter(line):
    command = os.system(f'cmd /c "{line}"')
    return command
```

Comment: The Python documentation for [os.system](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.system) declares this function as deprecated since many years. It should not be used anymore in new coded Python 3.x scripts. There should be used `subprocess.run` or `subprocess.call` or `subprocess.Popen`. The reason is that `os.system` results always in execution of `%ComSpec% /c` in background with the command line specified in the Python script appended as arguments. So the suggestion results in execution of `C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe /c cmd /c "..line.."` which makes never sense.

Comment: The usage help output on running `cmd /?` in a Windows command prompt window explains the special criteria applied on interpreting the argument string(s) after option `/C` (run command line and close) or option `/K` (run command line and keep running). The chance to get the `line` correct encoded for being interpreted by two `cmd.exe` processes is very low for a non-trivial command line. That is the reason why the developers of Python strongly recommend since years to use the `subprocess` module to have real control over the execution of any executable which is not possible with `os.system`.

Answer (score 0):

It's actually quite simple.
All you have to do is

```
import subprocess
def interpreter(line):
    proc = subprocess.Popen(line, shell=True, stdin=subprocess.PIPE, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
    out, err = proc.communicate()
    return out.decode(), err.decode()
```

You may have to change the target decode charset, depending on your language some characters may not fit into UTF-8.

Comment: Why should be used `shell=True`? Why should be run in background always `%ComSpec% /c` with the command line as defined with `line`? There is never the need to run an executable with `shell=True`, except the Windows command processor should be executed to execute an internal command of itself. But Python has functions for all internal commands of `cmd.exe` as Python is the much more powerful script interpreter. There is always the possibility to run explicitly `cmd.exe` with the arguments `/C` or `/K` without or with opening a console window and with whatever commands to execute by `cmd`.

Comment: Thanks, I tried it and I get the following error: AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'decode'

Comment: can you specify the command you're gonna run?
I tried it on my machine with "dir".
You could also not decode it and see what your result is!

Comment: @KaiE `dir` is very pure for testing a command line to execute. I suggest to create with Windows File Explorer the directory tree `C:\Temp\Development & Test(!)` and create in this directory with Windows Notepad the batch file `My'Test.cmd` with the single command line `@echo %0 %*& dir "%TEMP%"` and try to run from within the Python script the command line `"C:\Temp\Development & Test(!)\My'Test.cmd" Temporary files and directories > "%USERROFILE%\Desktop\%USERNAME%_Temp_%1.txt" & notepad.exe "%USERROFILE%\Desktop\%USERNAME%_Temp_%1.txt"` working absolutely fine in a command prompt window.